# The Android Product Flavors doesn't work

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I created 2 flavors (com.example.admin.deb) and (com.example.admin.lab_127) And the difference between this two packages is in the MainActivity.java file (just two lines of code). In the build.gradle I created

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.deb"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors{
    pro {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.lab_127"
    }
    deb {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.deb"
        dependencies {
            compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
            compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
            compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'

        }
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
```

}

But when I change Build Variant nothing happens.My folder structure like this:

```
-app
----manifests
------------AndroidManifest.xml
----java
--------com.example.admin.deb
-----------MainActivity.java
--------com.example.admin.lab_127
-----------data
-----------ItemAdapter.java
-----------MainActivity.java
----res
```

So what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a different version of the same class in the two flavor you'll need to create it in both flavors and **do not put it in src/main/java**. In your case:

```
src/deb/java/com/example/admin/deb/MainActivity.java
src/pro/java/com/example/admin/deb/MainActivity.java
```

You should implement  next structure:

```
app
  src
    deb
      java
         com.example.admin.deb
            MainActivity.java
    main
      java
         com.example.admin.deb
      res
    pro
      java
         com.example.admin.deb
            MainActivity.java
```

Comment: If this resolves your issue, please mark the answer as correct. It can help other users. thanks.